# Word or expression meaning a demonstration taken place on Twitter

Tags: single-word-requests

One form of internet activism is to post many messages on Twitter in a specified time frame. It is more specific than "hashtag activism" because, similarly to a demonstration that takes place on streets, it has a time to begin and to end.

Is there a word or expression for that?

In Portuguese, it is called "tuitaço".

Comment: Could *slacktivism* suit your purposes? It doesn't have the connotation of a beginning or end, though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slacktivism

Comment: @JLG, thanks, but _slacktivism_ is charged with the meaning of slacker, which, in my opinion, isn't always applicable to the activity described.

Answer (score 3):

I've often seen "twitterstorm" used to this effect, often in the acceptation of "shitstorm."

> His comments triggered a violent twitterstorm.

Comment: This just indicates a flurry of opposing tweets. It doesn't indicate these were aimed to happen within a specified time frame.

Comment: In some acceptations of the idiom, it can mean exactly what @toliveira is talking about, as explained [here](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/29624/twitterstorm), but the term is indeed too young to have a definitive meaning.

Comment: Your link doesn't support the idea. As far as I know the OP is talking about an idea where people agree to go onto Twitter between 16:00 and 18:00 next Friday and promote some cause. I don't see anything like that in your explanation.

Comment: Here's one example of the term used exactly in this acceptation: http://www.bustle.com/articles/6991-opmaryville-anonymous-calls-for-twitterstorm-and-courthouse-rally-to-protest-daisy-coleman-rape-case

Comment: OK I agree that does...

Comment: @MartinSmith, you interpreted correctly that the activity for which I look for a word happens within a specified time frame, e.g., between 16:00 and 18:00 next Friday. Stephane, thank you for your suggestion, which may be the closer I can get to the activity described. However, I don't agree that the example offered is used in this acception. It is about [this](http://pastebin.com/G0ahgG6Q) operation, which has a moment to start (Oct 15, 5PM EST) but, since it is aimed to promote a protest that will take place just one week later (Oct 22), most likely will not be concentrated in time.